# How to Stream the TV channel from TV Tuner Card in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, stream, channel, television

I have system with TV tuner card. In my project, I want to stream one of the channel from my system to other users in my LAN.

I don't have any idea how to stream TV channel from TV Tuner Card.

I want to use ASP.NET with C#.

Please help me to find out the solution for this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly TV Tuner cards uses Windows Media Encoder to encode the format that they are receiving from cable, so that TV Tuner Software can decode it and display in playable format. You may need to do the same by using Windows Media Plugin to get the stream of from the TV Tuner card into a HTTP stream. I guess VLC can stream the content from your TV Tuner to a HTTP Location and you can then take that stream and show it to the user via Windows Media player Plugin. I am not sure as how it will work though. Wish I could have any better answer for you.

Comment: May be this can help too.

http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/169292-How-to-stream-live-TV-using-Windows-Media-Encoder

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck using [Microsoft Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx) to broadcast the signal from a TV Tuner card over LAN.  There is a free trial you can use to see if it will work for you.

As far as incorporating it into an ASP.NET page, I have played around with using the HTML 5 video tag in Google Chrome to pick up a stream.  I ended up using VLC to transcode the output of Expression Encoder to an OGG (Theora + Vorbis) type.  The vlc command I used was:

vlc.exe -vvv http://127.0.0.1:8080 --sout #transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=3500000,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,audio-sync,threads=2,deinterlace}:http{dst=:8081/stream.ogg} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep

and then

```
<video autoplay controls>
  <source src="http://[yourServerIp]:8081/stream.ogg"  type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

Although I think there is an option in the paid version of Expression Encoder to encode right into h.264 which might allow you to skip the VLC step entirely.

Not sure if this will solve your problem entirely, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: VLC is the only thing I use for the transcoding step, yeah.  It is available here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ and is open source and available on pretty much everything.